# why doesn't selenium work properly on manjaro (PATH problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, manjaro

i just downloaded selenium and wanted to try just simple
code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

it also doesn't work if i change

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

to

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

i made gecko driver executable with chmod +x geckodriver

moved it to usr/local/bin

and set path like that:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

still doesn't work

with webdriver-manager the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/keksik/JetBainz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Answer (score 1):

Appearently, the issue occurs due to non-administrative privileges. The location where you have your driver at needs root privileges to be executed/run. I suggest you moving your driver to somewhere in your home directory where you don't need root privileges to launch the driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can always install the Firefox driver on the fly. Just make sure you have the normal version of firefox installed. This doesn't have any kind of dependency on your local setup.

All you need to do is:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

from

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
```

Comment: when i pip install webdriver it says 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: none)

Comment: Because there is no python package called webdriver.
This is within the selenium package

Comment: Directly import from selenium

Comment: My bad try `pip install webdriver-manager` or `pip3` if you have that

Comment: what's the problem

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")`

Comment: same error
i edited the post so i can post full error

Comment: Do you have firefox installed on your machine??

Comment: yes of course
it opens up using this code but doesn't go to site nor youtube nor google
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe")
browser.get('http://google.com/')
browser.quit()